# How to Prepend a Column in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`Dataframe.withColumns()` appends only a new column at the end of the dataframe, however i need a way to **prepend** it.

is that possible ?

or the only solution is to create a dataframe with my column and then append the rest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "prepend column" in spark, but you can re-order the columns using `select`:

in python:

```
df.withColumn("column_name", ...).select("column_name", *df.columns)
```

in scala:

```
df.withColumn("column_name", ...).select("column_name", df.columns:_*)
```

Comment: thanks but update your answer , insted of "*df.columns" , just put 'the rest of columns"

Comment: @A.HADDAD: If you are using scala you can do `df.columns:_*`.

Comment: yes you re right @Shaido